# There's no line here to end: figure caption: apa7 documentclass: Overleaf

Tags: floats, captions, overleaf, apa7

Using this minimal example in Overleaf I get an error.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, doc,  12pt]{apa7}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}

\title{Title}
\shorttitle{Short}

\begin{document}

Some text
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \includegraphics{example-image} 
        \caption{Image}
    \end{figure}
Some more text
    
\end{document}
```

`There's no line here to end. \caption{Image}`

If I change the documentclass to apa6, the error disappears. I've also got the same error using TexStudio locally. I have tried many things, too many to count, but my expertise is not sufficient to give a coherent story. The error is not fatal, so it doesn't really matter, but it would be excellent to make it disappear and I might learn something on the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class defines the separator to be two consecutive `\\`  which is always going to give that error with standard definitions (but "almost" works in this class, with a warning).

```
\documentclass[a4paper, doc,  12pt]{apa7}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
% \DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{apalabelsep}{\\ \\}%what!!
 \DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{apalabelsep}{\\}
\title{Title}
\shorttitle{Short}

\begin{document}

Some text
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \includegraphics{example-image} 
        \caption{Image}
    \end{figure}
Some more text
    
\end{document}
```

the usual advice with publisher classes is *not* to change the layout, the whole point is to remove choice from the author and enforce a house style.
If you do not redefine the caption layout it works without error, just warning from the `\\ \\`

```
\documentclass[a4paper, doc,  12pt]{apa7}
\usepackage{float}

\title{Title}
\shorttitle{Short}

\begin{document}

Some text
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \includegraphics{example-image} 
        \caption{Image}
    \end{figure}
Some more text
    
\end{document}
```

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 12--12
```

Comment: @Ingmar thanks..

Comment: No publisher is going to be harmed in the making of my document so if I want to centre my captions I have to use `\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{apalabelsep}{\\}` to stop the warning. I can live with that.

Comment: @AndrewChisholm that's why I gave both versions, If you were submitting to an apa journal I'd choose the other. Either way you could report it to the maintaiers, the coding is... unusual.

Comment: I have raised it, hopefully to the right place.

Answer (score 0):

It's really hard to understand what the class authors want when they do

```
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{apalabelsep}{\\ \\}
```

in `doc` mode, because this just produces a warning and nothing really sensible.

In any case they also do

```
\captionsetup[table]{
  position=above,
  skip=0pt,
  labelformat=tablelabel,
  labelsep=apalabelsep,
  textformat=tabletext
}
\captionsetup[figure]{
  position=above,
  skip=0pt,
  labelformat=figurelabel,
  labelsep=apalabelsep,
  textfont=it
}
```

which means that they expect captions to be *above* figures and not below them.

Here's the output in modes `man`, `doc` and `jou` (with the caption above):

[image]

[image]

[image]

You get the same output in all modes and avoid warnings with

```
\documentclass[
  a4paper,
%  man,
%  jou,
  doc,
  12pt,
]{apa7}

% fix the warning caused by "\\ \\" which is a wrong LaTeX construct
\ifapamode{% man
  % nothing to change
}{% jou
    \DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{apalabelsep}{\\[\baselineskip]}
}{% doc%    \DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{apalabelsep}{\\[\baselineskip]}
}


\title{Title}
\shorttitle{Short}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\caption{Image (doc mode)}
\includegraphics[width=6cm]{example-image} 
\end{figure}
    
\end{document}
```

Don't change the positioning of the captions if you want to submit a paper to a journal or an institution requiring `apa7`. In other cases, avoid the class, which does a disputable typesetting job.